# Property '_id' does not exist on type 'string | JwtPayload'. Property '_id' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, jwt

As you can see in the NodeJS code I'm grabbing the user from the token from Postman provided in the URL but I'm struggling to get back the _id property from the given token number. What I want is that id in the decoded._id so that I can use that id in further operations

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const User = require('../model/users')
const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
          const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer', '')
          const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'thisisfromabhishek')

`the property _id does not exist on decoded`
          const user = await User.findOne({ _id: decoded._id, 'tokens.token': token })

        if (!user) {
            throw new Error()
        }
        req.token = token
        req.user = user
        next()
       } catch (e) {
        res.status(401).send({ error: 'Please authenticate.' })
    }
}

module.exports = auth
```

Comment: could you log decode variable ?

Comment: it not showing me any error in console its just not grabbing the _id property some autocomplete from the editor but because of that I'm not able to grab _id

Comment: can you please show your token?

Comment: "tokens" : [ 
        {
            "token" : "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2MTVlZWY1MmM4NTZlYmFkMTM3NTIzNjIiLCJpYXQiOjE2MzM2MTE2MDJ9.13oo0gCXb_fGyElG4g3Uakf2g7LGdih6fV5pHOK6vkI",
            "_id" : ObjectId("615eef52c856ebad13752364")
        }
    ]

Comment: so your token is stored in a JSON. What is the exact value of `token`  that you pass to `jwt.verify(token...`?  It should be only the token itself, `eyJhb.....`

Comment: this value of token passing in "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2MTVlZWY1MmM4NTZlYmFkMTM3NTIzNjIiLCJpYXQiOjE2MzM2MTE2MDJ9.13oo0gCXb_fGyElG4g3Uakf2g7LGdih6fV5pHOK6vkI" in Postman headers in Authorization key

Comment: if you have a string "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUz..." and then just remove the word "Bearer", you still have a blank in front of the token, e.g. " eyJhbGciOiJIUz..." . Could this be the problem?

Comment: I did tried that after your recommendation but still I'm not getting the desired result I think its of the _id only because it's still showing me the same and it's getting the _id

Answer (score 32):

Typescript don't know about _id in token.
Data declaration should help.

```
interface JwtPayload {
  _id: string
}

const { _id } = jwt.verify(token, 'thisisfromabhishek') as JwtPayload

req.user = await User.findOne({ _id, 'tokens.token': token })
```

Answer (score 1):

Typescript don't know about _id in token, add JwtPayloqd type or interface with id

```
interface JwtPayload {
    id: string;
}

const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET!) as JwtPayload;
console.log(decoded);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

you have not given space after Bearer.

```js
const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer', '') //here is the problem place space after Bearer
          const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'thisisfromabhishek')
```

Answer (score 0):

The typescript doesn't know about your types, so you can easily write precise type with this way(It's necessary part of the code:

```
import jwt, { JwtPayload } from "jsonwebtoken";
import { RequestHandler } from "express";

interface IJwtPayload extends JwtPayload {
  _id: string;
}

const auth: RequestHandler = async (req, res, next) => {
  const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'JWT_SECRET_KEY') as IJwtPayload;

  req.user = await User.findOne({ _id: decoded._id, 'tokens.token': token })
}
```